# How to use array member?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

Why I get error when used **struct array** in **struct**?

```
public struct Tables
{
    public string name;
}

public struct Schema
{
    public string name;
    public Tables[] tables; //Declarate struct array in struct
}
```

I used struct with this code:

```
Schema schema;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    schema.name = "schemaName";
    schema.tables[0].name = "tables1Name"; // Error in here: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
}
```

Comment: I've removed mentioning of struct from title... Feel free to revert the edit if disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your array:

```
schema.name = "schemaName";
schema.tables = new Tables[10];
schema.tables[0].name = "tables1";
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because `schema.tables` was never initialized, and is therefore null

try

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    schema.name = "schemaName";
    schema.tables = new Tables[5];
    schema.tables[0].name = "tables1"; // Error ini here: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
}
```